# How can I move the client to an other html file after number input

Tags: javascript, html, css

After a number **input submission** I want to go from the index.html file to an other html file or something like that.

Can somebody help me?

That's the code i wrote:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link rel="icon" href="nick.jpg">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Bet</h1>

  <form action="cool.html">
    <label class="amountMoney" for="amountMoney">Input the amount of money you want. The money will be converted in dollars</label>
    <h3>The value can't be more than 100 or less than 10</h3>
    <input id="amountMoney" type="number" placeholder="Amount of money" min="10" max="100" required>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
  <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

*Btw I'm linking a different css file in cool.html*

Comment: "*I want to go from the index.html file to an other html file or something like that.*" - explain precisely what you want to happen, "**or something like that**" is not a useful description of your problem or expectations. Also, show the code you've written in an attempt to solve your problem. Please, read the following: "*[mcve]*", "*[ask]*" and take the [tour] to understand our expectations of a question, and *why* we have those expectations.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re just using html (no scripting language) you need to do it this way, using the method and action parameters at the top of your form:

```
<form method="post" action="cool.html">
```

Or you can redirect to a new page after processing the form server side, if that applies to your case scenario.